# How can I draw a dot under a symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I'm trying to find the equivalent to `\d` (or `\textsubdot`) for the math mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `\underaccent` command from the [`accents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) package. Something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand*\underdot[1]{%
  \underaccent{\dot}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\underdot{A}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But be aware of this annoying issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176273/when-using-the-accents-package-underaccent-greek-symbol-in-caption-of-a-table-g

Answer (score 5):

It's not in the TeX Book. If you don't mind cheating you could try the following but it's not nice:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\myd#1{\text{\d{\ensuremath#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\myd{a}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Understandably this is a *minimal* working example. However, rather use a documentclass *other* than `minimal` (like `article`, say). I think `\ensuremath` here is a bit much, since you want the contents of `\myd` to be in math mode *always*. As such, rather use `\d{$#1$}` - just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me for this old answer..but it is possibile to use also this code to get the dot under a symbol or a character.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\d{o}, \d{$\alpha$}, \d{$\xi$}, \d{$\epsilon$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `\xi` symbol it is not very good.