# When using the accents package: underaccent greek symbol in caption of a table gives error

Tags: errors, captions, accents, greek

I am using the accents package to place a bar under math symbols. This works very well when using it in equations, and also in normal text (obviously still in the math environment $...$). However, currently I am creating a table with a caption and it does not want to compile. I preferably do not want to use \underbar.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a
\end{tabular}
\caption{$\ubar{\pi}$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

First **error** when using PDFTeXify in WinEdt 8.0 and MiKTeX 2.9 (I actually receive 100 errors).

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\underaccent #1#2->\begingroup \def \cc@a
                                           {#2}\cc@palette \cc@underaccent {#...
1.12 \caption{$\ubar{\pi}$}

The control sequence at the end of the top line 
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have 
misspelled it (e.g. `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct 
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\caption{$\protect\ubar{\pi}$}`? Captions are “moving arguments“, errors of that kind usually mean that some command has to be preceded by `\protect`. Or use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}`

Comment: @egreg That works. Wow! Thanks a lot. Just saw your edit. Both options work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `accents` package defines command that are not robust: for instance we find

```
\newcommand\underaccent[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\cc@a{#2}% Stores the nucleous...
    \cc@palette\cc@underaccent{#1}% ...and the accent is passed
    #2%
  \endgroup}
```

A command like this will not survive being found in a “moving argument” (the argument to `\caption`, `\chapter`, `\section` and similar commands). Defining `\ubar` in terms of `\underaccent` makes `\ubar` share the same fragility.

The package really ought to do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\underaccent[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\cc@a{#2}% Stores the nucleous...
    \cc@palette\cc@underaccent{#1}% ...and the accent is passed
    #2%
  \endgroup}
```

so the problem would disappear.

There are various fixes. The first is putting `\protect` in front of the command when it appears in a moving argument:

```
\caption{$\protect\ubar{\pi}$}
```

A better fix would be providing the protection to *your* command

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
```

instead of using `\newcommand`.

An even better fix would be to remedy to the glitch in `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{accents}

\MakeRobust{\underaccent} % make \underaccent not fragile in moving arguments

\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{$\ubar{\pi}$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `fixltx2e` you can use `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{accents}
\robustify{\underaccent}
```

would do the same (in a different way).