# Accents package not working inside captions

Tags: captions, accents, underline

I'm writing a document involving phasors and I'd like to use egreg's notation from this post: [\bar below symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125412/bar-below-symbol/125414#125414), e.g. `$\underaccent{\bar}{U}$`.

It works well except if I put the phasor inside a caption. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item An ugly phasor: $\underline{U}$.
\item Another, better good-looking phasor: $\underaccent{\bar}{U}$.
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3,0) node [right] {$\underaccent{\bar}{U}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{One phasor.}
%\caption{One phasor $\underaccent{\bar}{U}$.} % <-- NOT WORKING
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3,0) node [right] {$\underaccent{\bar}{V}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Another phasor.}
%\captionof{figure}{Another phasor $\underaccent{\bar}{V}$.} % <-- NOT WORKING EITHER
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I tried a workaround with the caption package, but to no avail. I think the relevant lines in my log file are probably the following, but I don't understand them:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\cc@@accent #1#2->\let \cc@style 
                                 =#1\cc@fetch {#2}\mathaccent \cc@code {\ifc...

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

I suppose that there is some kind of incompatibility with the accents package and the captions but I haven't seen anything about it in the documentation. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm working with TeX Live 2020, by the way.

Comment: Do you need a list of figures? If not, probably `\caption[]{One phasor $\underaccent{\bar}{U}$.}`results in the expected output? Likewise `\captionof{figure}[]{Another phasor $\underaccent{\bar}{V}$.}` should work.

Comment: @leandriis, yes it works, and no I don't need a list of figures, so this solves my problem, thanks!!

Comment: Also works `\protect\underaccent{\bar}{U}`, but only without `\listoffigures`

Comment: @leandriis, I'm curious about the cause, what is the problem here?

Comment: @Ivan, indeed it works too. Thanks!!

Comment: Here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176277/231952 @egreg suggests to use `\usepackage{fixltx2e} \MakeRobust{\underaccent}` or `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify{\underaccent}`. Anyway `\listoffigures` returns an error even with these two solutions. So the issue is still open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you use [`\DeclareRobustCommand`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{itemize}
\item An ugly phasor: $\underline{U}$.
\item Another, better good-looking phasor: $\underaccent{\bar}{U}$.
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3,0) node [right] {$\underaccent{\bar}{U}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{One phasor $\ubar{U}$.} 
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (3,0) node [right] {$\underaccent{\bar}{V}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Another phasor $\ubar{V}$.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: The underlying issue is that the `accents` package did not follow the suggestion of [the clsguide, section 2.6](https://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide), and so all the accent commands are [fragile](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-protect).

Comment: This fails in section titles, even with ```\protect```.

Comment: @Cryme it works just fine in a minimal document I just tested. If for some reason it breaks for you, please consider asking a new question with an MWE included. Feel free to ping me on this comment thread if you'd like my input.