# Manually constructing a dot under accent

Tags: spacing

In my thesis I would like to have an n with the combining dot under diacritic, but unfortunately my font doesn't have that particular accent, I figured I could try to construct it ad hoc (since I just need it in a single place) from a plain n and a period. I tried various things, shifting the period down a few points and twiddling with hskips, but nothing really works.

Is there a way to do this that both looks decent as well as preserving my sanity?

Comment: As always it is a good idea to post a minimal example showing what exactly you have so far. Then it is a lot easier for others to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: You should post a minimal compilable example. Doesn't `\d n` work? And `\underdot n`?

Comment: It would help to have an image of what you want.

Comment: Is perhaps this question helping you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex

Comment: if you need it in math mode, see this question: [How can I draw a dot under a symbol in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39844/579)

Comment: Yeah, this was a badly worded question, sorry. Thankfully, Heiko Oberdiek's constructed solution works. \d does not, at least not with XeLaTeX, since my font (Adobe Minion) doesn't have that accent (neither the precomposed character, nor the combining dot below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Accent macro `\d`

The accent `\d` also works with OT1 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \d{n}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## A constructed solution via `\ooalign`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \ooalign{n\cr\hfil\raisebox{-.5ex}{.}\hfil}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Such a nice suggestions, helps me too, thanks, have a happy and wonderful New Year 2024