# Adding two diacritical points under letters

Tags: spacing, letterspacing, diacritical-mark

I'm working on a glossary with some transliterated Persian, Urdu and Arabic. Conforming with earlier publications, I sometimes need to use two diacritical dots under letters such as `s`, `z` and `t`. I've tried to solve this with `\ooalign`, inspired by [the answer given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222377/manually-constructing-a-dot-under-accent/222383#222383). I can now place two dots below these letters, but the problem is that as a result the spacing between letters is no longer pleasant. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{%
    \ooalign{#1\cr\hfil\raisebox{-.5ex}{..}\hfil}%
    }

\Huge{%
\d{H}\={a}fi\dd{z}, Shams-ud-D\={\i}n Mu\d{h}ammad

Other examp\dd{l}e.%
}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: example two diacritical points]

How do I fix the letter spacing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\ooalign` is not the right tool.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCcommand{\dd}[1]{%
  \vtop{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr % template
      #1\cr % top line
      \noalign{\vspace{0.25ex}}% space
      \hidewidth.\kern-0.1em.\hidewidth\cr % dots
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\d{H}\={a}fi\dd{z}, Shams-ud-D\={\i}n Mu\d{h}ammad

Other examp\dd{l}e.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Mimicking the plain definition for `\d` works well.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{{\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr \hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\kern-.1em.\hidewidth}}}
\makeatother

{\Huge
    \d{H}\={a}fi\dd{z}, Shams-ud-D\={\i}n Mu\d{h}ammad

    Other examp\dd{l}e.%
}
```

[image: output]

Also, note that `\Huge` doesn't take an argument, but is a font switch command.

Answer (score 5):

With a very simple modification of your code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}

    \newcommand{\dd}[1]{%
     \ooalign{#1\cr\hfil\raisebox{-.5ex}{\clap{..}}\hfil}%
        }

    \Huge{%
    \d{H}\={a}fi\dd{z}, Shams-ud-D\={\i}n Mu\d{h}ammad

    Other examp\dd{l}e.%
    }

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Totally different approach: Why not simply make use of Unicode's U+0323 COMBINING DOT BELOW and U+0324 COMBINING DIAERESIS BELOW?

> Ḥāfiz̤, Shams-ud-Dīn Muḥammad
>
> Other exampl̤e

Comment: (note that this only works in Unicode engines -- unless/until the LaTeX team decide to add support for it, but it doesn't look like the case now. The OP presumably is using pdflatex (or copy pasting some wrong code that use inputenc))

Comment: Yes, obviously this would require using either LuaLaTeX or XeTeX. That said, there is generally very little reason not to in the first place, particularly when support vor “exotic” languages or writing systems might be required.

Comment: @user202729 I believe the LaTeX team has said that Unicode combining characters are not going to work in 8-bit TeX, due to inherent architectural limitations.

Comment: Ah right, only Unicode characters that already have the diacritic precomposed works.